# include .dll into another workflow project without using reference

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is there a way to load an .dll, and extract the activities ( .xaml) and run them without adding the .dll as references in the new project?

Could you please give me an example?

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
    WorkflowApplication wfapp = new WorkflowApplication(xaml from dll);
      wfapp.Run();
```

Comment: If the DLL has an xaml workflow, it should be compiled as a type and would be instantiatable via Activator.CreateInstance.  Open the DLL in JustDecompile and see if the workflow you want is in there as a class.

Comment: oki, thx. Is there any other way to run a workflow dll, in the new project without adding it to reference? Am automatic way in which for example, the workflow from the project "see" the dll and runs it when necessary?

Comment: Would Microsoft Dynamic CRM be helpfull?

Comment: could you give me a sample code of how to do this?

Comment: CRM, no.  You'd AppDomain.Load an assembly, then enumerate the types it contains to find your workflow, then use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of that type.  There's plenty of examples here on how to do that.  Search for "Load assembly at runtime" and the Activator method call.  Use JustDecompile to open your workflow DLL to see if your workflows are compiled, first.  Have you done that?

Comment: I have decompiled the workflow. yes. i will continue with the steps mentioned, and i'll be back with a feedback. thx